# How can I get a mouse cursor in qemu?

Tags: 14.04, qemu

I am using 14.04 on an AMD64 compatible system. Inside this system I am trying to run a virtual machine also with 14.04. I start qemu with this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso -m 2048
```

Ubuntu boots inside qemu. But as soon as I move the mouse inside the qemu window, the cursor turns invisible. I can click on items just inside the border of the virtual screen, and this works so I know the mouse emulation is sort of working.

However since the cursor is invisible I have no idea where I am clicking when I try to click on something close to the center of the virtual screen.

What do I need to do to make the mouse cursor visible in qemu?

Comment: Is  there a typo somewhere or are you actually trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM under 14.04?

Comment: @ElderGeek No typo. Yes I am trying to run 14.04 in a VM under 14.04.

Comment: I find that a bit puzzling, but I'm glad you got it sorted out. ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek I have my reasons. Next I am going to try to run qemu inside of that.  Though with the slowdown I get from one layer of emulation, I don't think I'll ever manage to boot two layers of emulation. I suspect qemu might have been the wrong choice.

Comment: @ElderGeek I just tried virtualbox instead. It turns out that virtualbox boots 12 times faster than qemu.

Comment: And Ubuntu boots much faster natively than it does on a VM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out all I had to do was to add `-show-cursor` to the command line. Additionally I found that adding `-enable-kvm` reduced the bootup time from 10 minutes to 45 seconds. This version works:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -show-cursor -enable-kvm -cdrom ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso -m 2048
```

I find it a bit puzzling why this is not turned on by default.

Answer (score 3):

The provided answer is a little outdated... at time of writing adding:

```
-display default,show-cursor=on
```

did the trick.